# How to sum a int64 and object type?

Tags: python, pandas

I have the following dataframe:

```
Setup   Setup1  Setup2

720       60    540

360       60    180

300       0      0

1,8       60    60

600       60    540

Setup = object
Setup1 = int64
Setup2 = int64
```

I would like to sum all setup times into one measures. This is what I do:

```
totalduration2 = (np.sum(dfgroup2[['Setup1', 'Setup2','Setup']].values))
```

However it results in a NaN value, this is probably due to the int64 and object types. I tried to change it with:

```
df2['SetupDuration1'] = df2['SetupDuration1'].convert_objects(convert_numeric=True)
df2['SetupDuration2'] = df2['SetupDuration2'].convert_objects(convert_numeric=True)
df2['Duration'] = df2['Duration'].convert_objects(convert_numeric=True)
```

The issue with the dot instead of a comma is solved for now, however 1.8 means 1800. So how could I chance the values that contain a . with a factor 1000?

```
IF cell contains a dot . THEN
    value*1000
```

Comment: Someone who can help me with the 1.8 times 1000 issue?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

First you need to change the `NaN` values to proper floats:

```
df['Setup'] = df['Setup'].apply(lambda x: float(str(x).replace(',', '.')) if ',' in str(x) else float(x))
```

Or more dynamically for all the columns:

```
for col in df.columns:
    df[col] = df[col].apply(lambda x: float(str(x).replace(',', '.')) if ',' in str(x) and 'Setup' in col else float(x))
```

Then you can sum all the `Setup` columns:

```
setup_sum = sum(sum(df[col].values) for col in df.columns if 'Setup' in col)
```

Comment: that does not work, because the value 1,8 is treated as a NaN value. I think that is the problem why the sum does not work, so how can I fix that 1,8 is seen as a value?

Comment: 1,8 comes from my dataset, but it should be 1.8 because it results in a NaN value, so how to fix?

Comment: that should result in 601.8 @DeepSpace

Comment: So you need to change that value to `1.8`, either in the dataframe or in your database,

Comment: yes but this dataset is quite large, so is there a way to do it with a line of code?

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/84075/discussion-between-deepspace-and-f1990).